# qt qml: fade image horizontally (i.e from left to right ... not whole image)

Tags: qt, qml

[image]i m showing 3 images horizontally at a time using PathLine. 
The left and right image need to be shown as 50% faded from left & 50% faded from right.
Here i cannot use a black rectangle gradient to show the fade effect as my parent is 20% transparent & it floats on a background video.

So is there any ways to apply the opacity property as a horizontal fade animation?

Comment: I think you have to do this using a shader effect... Are you using QML1 (Qt4) or QML2 (Qt5)?

Comment: m using Qt 4.7. I have gone through ShaderEffects example but dont understand how will i use it for my purpose. I just need the image to fade out towards the end with animation while approaching the edge of pathLine

Comment: So what you basically need is a per-pixel opacity. I'm wondering if this will be the same for the whole scene (so you just have a fade-out at the edges of the whole scene) or if you want to apply such a alpha mask to single images. Could you try to draw a sketch or be a bit more specific about how the animations will work? What I don't understand: You said you have a fade animation. But I think you want to move the images along a path, the most left & right ones fading out when they go out of the scene. So essentially you want the scene border to be smooth?

Comment: yes u r getting it rite.. actually i dnt have 10+ reputation so not allowing me to attach image.. i could have applied alpha mask (black to transparent gradient) to the whole parent at edges.. but as my parent is translusent (to watch the background video even when the menu slides out) i cannot mask.. It will show black patch in my Menu instead of complete black background with opacity 0.6..

Comment: and regarding fade animation... its just that while the image moves from center to right, i want to reduce the opacity gradually from left to right.. as if its approaching towards a black gradient mask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [QML `ShaderEffectItem` element](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qml-shadereffectitem.html) you can add post-effects to a QML item using a shader program. This enables you to do some graphics effects on the GPU.

As you see in the documentation I've linked above, this can for example be a wave effect. In general, you apply a small "program" to every output pixel. This is the so-called *fragment shader* in GLSL.

To give you an idea of how you could implement a alpha mask on an item (this might be your scene which contains the images on the path which you are animating), I'll give an example in which I implement a simple linear gradient as the alpha mask, where on the left we have zero opacity and on the right full opacity.

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import Qt.labs.shaders 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    id: wrapper

    Item {
        id: scene
        anchors.fill: parent
        // Here is your scene with the images ...
    }

    ShaderEffectItem {
        anchors.fill: wrapper

        // Any property you add to the ShaderEffectItem is accessible as a
        // "uniform" value in the shader program. See GLSL doc for details.
        // Essentially, this is a value you pass to the fragment shader,
        // which is the same for every pixel, thus its name.

        // Here we add a source item (the scene) as a uniform value. Within the
        // shader, we can access it as a sampler2D which is the type used to
        // access pixels in a texture. So the source item becomes a texture.
        property variant source: ShaderEffectSource
        {
            sourceItem: scene // The item you want to apply the effect to
            hideSource: true  // Only show the modified item, not the original
        }

        // This is the fragment shader code in GLSL (GL Shading Language)
        fragmentShader: "
        varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;  // The coords within the source item
        uniform sampler2D source;         // The source item texture
        void main(void)
        {
            // Read the source color of the pixel
            vec4 sourceColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);

            // The alpha value of the mask
            float alpha = qt_TexCoord0.x; // = 0.0 at left, 1.0 at right border

            // Multiply the alpha mask on the color to be drawn:
            sourceColor *= alpha;

            // Write the pixel to the output image
            gl_FragColor = sourceColor;
        }
        "
    }
}
```

The most important line in the shader program is the value of the `alpha` variable. In this small example I just set the X component of the texture coordinate as the alpha value, thus at the left border it is 0, at the right border it is 1. Note that the texture coordinates are not measured in pixels but in a [0..1] range. If you want to access pixel coordinates, you can use `gl_FragCoord.x`/`y`. Note that `y` is measured from bottom to top, so 0 is the bottom border and `height` is the top border. Per default you can't access the `height` of the whole resulting image, but therefore we can use uniforms. Just assign a new `property int h: height` and access it using `uniform float h` in the shader.

Comment: Hm... Something seems to be wrong... But I can't figure out what.

Comment: My problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13161296 Maybe you don't have this problem...

Comment: let me try this... but still i feel cant there be a more simpler solution to this.. like a fading Edge for PathLine or something?? :)

Comment: @nit I'm sorry, I don't think Qt can give you this out of the box. However, there also is something like a alpha mask effect (but called different...) in the Qt-Components project. But I think this will do it in software which will be very inefficient if your scene fills the whole screen. You definitely should go the GPU-accelerated way for such effects. Also note that for this example you have to enable OpenGL. In a QML-only project, add `-opengl` to the qmlviewer arguments; in a C++ project, use a `QGLWidget` as the viewport if you aren't doing this already.

Comment: hi..  i have attached image (edited my question).. so do u think i ll achieve it with shader's effect

Comment: @nit Yeah, this looks like exactly what I was thinking about. So you could define an alpha mask for the "scene of images" (so for the menu, I think this is what you want to do here) instead of one mask for the left-most image and one for the right-most image (because they change over time, this is much more complicated). You will have one static alpha mask and in combination with the images in the scene you'll get exactly what you wanted. And finally I fixed the error I was talking about in the two comments. :)

Comment: Thanks leemes, but i found a simpler way &  finally achieved this using QGraphicsOpacityEffect.. :)

Comment: @nit Okay, didn't know this effect. However, note that (I think) this will render on your CPU rather than GPU and thus be very slow on large scenes. But if your menu is that small (as in your example image) it should be fine.

Comment: ohh.. so u mean QGraphicsOpacityEffect is heavier than ShaderEffect? or u mean using a Qt class in qml will be heavier.. plz brief..

Comment: @nit I mean QGraphicsOpacityEffect is slower than ShaderEffect, regardless if used in C++ or QML. But I might be wrong, maybe QGraphicsOpacityEffect also uses OpenGL. You can try: just make your menu very large for testing. Use a QGLWidget as the viewport of the declarative view. Then compare the render performance with/without a QGraphicsOpacityEffect and you will see...